# What is the error(s) in this latex code for ECC equation?

Tags: equations

%Equation 1

```
\begin{equation}
E(\textit{p},\textit{a},\textit{b})=\Big\{(\textit{x},\textit{y}) | \textit{x},\textit{y} \in\mathbb{Z_\textit{p},\textit{y^2}=\textit{x^3}+\textit{ax}+\textit{b},\mod\textit{p}}\Big}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` as always

Comment: Variables are automatically italic in math; this is not the way to use `textit`.

Answer (score 7):

You have two obvious errors:

```
\mathbb{Z_\textit{p}
```

lacks a closing brace and, at the end,

```
\Big}
```

lacks a backslash before `}`.

However, you should be aware that LaTeX allows for much easier input: letters will be in italics in math mode without any special instruction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E(p,a,b)=\bigl\{(x,y) \mid x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{p},y^2=x^3+ax+b\bigr\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't see reasons for specifying “mod *p*”, as you're working in the integers modulo *p* to begin with. Also `\Big` size is too big for this case.

Comment: +1. A minor suggestion: replace `\mid`  with `\bigm\vert`.

Comment: Possibly, but personally I wouldn’t use big size to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

In general, inside `math` the `alpha numerals` are in `italic` and `arabic` numerals are in `roman`, so no need to give `\textit` for each alpha characters, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E(p,a,b)=\Big\{(x,y) | x,y \in\mathbb{Z}_{p},y^2=x^3+ax+b,\mod p\Big\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

As you didn't mention the class file name, hence I've used the standard one